# Android Studio: How to send HTTPS requests to Node.js Server which is using self-signed certificate?

Tags: android, node.js, ssl, https, certificate

I'd need some help with an Android App here:
Basically I'm trying to send `HTTPS` requests to a Server developed in `Node.js`. This server is using self-signed certificate.
Now I know Android needs `AsyncTask` in order to send HTTPS requests, so I managed to implement as below:

```
public class RequestSender extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "GET";
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15000;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
        String stringUrl = params[0];
        String result = "RES";
        String inputLine;
        try {
            //Create a URL object holding our url
            URL myUrl = new URL(stringUrl);

            //Create a connection
            HttpsURLConnection connection =(HttpsURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();

            //Set methods and timeouts
            connection.setHostnameVerifier(new AllowAllHostnameVerifier());
            connection.setRequestMethod(REQUEST_METHOD);
            connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            //Connect to our url
            connection.connect();

            //Create a new InputStreamReader
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());

            //Create a new buffered reader and String Builder
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            //Check if the line we are reading is not null
            while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
            }

            //Close our InputStream and Buffered reader
            reader.close();
            streamReader.close();

            //Set our result equal to our stringBuilder
            result = stringBuilder.toString();
            Log.d("REQ", "Result received: " + result);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = "";
            Log.e("REQ", "REQ Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

In order to test it, this is what I do in `MainActivity`:

```
RequestSender rSender = new RequestSender();
        rSender.execute(CommandSender.AUTH);
        try {
            String res = rSender.get();
            if(res != null)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Response NOT NULL: " + res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Response: NULL!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException | ExecutionException ecc){
            ecc.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now, if I use previous `AsyncTask` to send an HTTPS request to `https://www.google.com` I get Google's html code, which is good. 
That means my `AsyncTask` works right?

Issue is, it doesn't work if I send HTTPS request to my `Node.js` Server, which is online and running. 
I thought self-signed certificate it's using may be the issue, so I added this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/cert"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

to `res/xml/network_security_config.xml` and Certificate used in Server in

```
res/raw/cert.pem
```

After all this, I still get empty response. `Toast` shown in `MainActivity` only prints: `Response NOT NULL!:`

What do I have to do in order to make things work here?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like request does not arrive at all, since in Server's log there's nothing new

Answer (score 0):

first of all I have two questions.

1. Have you tested the request with wget or curl?
2. Have you added the network security configuration to the AndroidManifest.xml?

cheers

Comment: Answer is yes to both questions: Added android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config to manifest and sending request with curl prints correct response on console, with --insecure option of course.

Comment: in case you solve the problem, would appreciate if you can maybe share it, I am dealing with the same situation.